# Anadir múltiples elementos a un object con un evento click

Tags: javascript, typescript

estoy creando una aplicación y necesito que al hacer click para seleccionar  un elemento dentro del ng-for se agregue a un **object**, la idea es que ese object tenga tantos elementos fueron seleccionados.

Yo lo logre hacer con un array, pero necesito que sea un object para poder acceder a su propiedad, por ejemplo, product.descripcionProducto.

Intentando con el object puedo agregar, pero solo se añade un único elemento, como muestra la consola, **cuando deberían ser 2**.

funcion click

```js
 public checkedProducts: Array<any> = [];
 public orderList: {};
  
  pressEvent(product) {
  // object
  this.orderList = {
   cantidad: product.cantidad,
   descripcionProducto: product.descripcionProducto,
   precioProducto: product.precioProducto,
  };
  // array
  this.checkedProducts.push(
   product.descripcionProducto,
   product.precioProducto,
   product.cantidad);
 }
  
  displayOrder() {
  // object
  console.dir(this.orderList);
  // array
  console.dir(this.checkedProducts);
 }
```

[image: app y consola de salida]

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder agregar elementos a tu Objeto lo tienes que asignar como un array ya que un Objeto no tiene la función `.push` cual está previsto para los matrizes `[]` (array).

Ejemplo convertido de Typescript a Javascript:

```js
var Prueba = (function () {
    function Prueba() {
        var _this = this;
        this.orderList = [];
        var product = {
            cantidad: 2,
            descripcionProducto: 'otro ejemplo',
            precioProducto: 2000
        };
        setTimeout(function () {
            _this.pressEvent(product);
        }, 1000);
    }
    Prueba.prototype.pressEvent = function (product) {
        this.orderList.push({
            cantidad: product.cantidad,
            descripcionProducto: product.descripcionProducto,
            precioProducto: product.precioProducto,
        });
        this.displayOrder();
    };
    Prueba.prototype.displayOrder = function () {
        console.log('Resultado: ', JSON.stringify(this.orderList));
    };
    return Prueba;
}());
var prueba = new Prueba();
prueba.pressEvent({
    cantidad: 1,
    descripcionProducto: 'ejemplo',
    precioProducto: 1000
});
```

En Typescript:

```
class Prueba {

    orderList: Array<Object> = [];   

    constructor() {

        let product = {
            cantidad: 2,
            descripcionProducto: 'otro ejemplo',
            precioProducto: 2000
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.pressEvent(product);
        },1000);        
     }

    pressEvent(product) {

        this.orderList.push({
            cantidad: product.cantidad,
            descripcionProducto: product.descripcionProducto,
            precioProducto: product.precioProducto,
        });

        this.displayOrder();
    }

    displayOrder() {
        console.log('Resultado: ', JSON.stringify(this.orderList);      
    }    
}

let prueba = new Prueba();

prueba.pressEvent({
            cantidad: 1,
            descripcionProducto: 'ejemplo',
            precioProducto: 1000
        });
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho, funciona de maravilla.